# Select cells to the left of filtered values - VBA

Tags: excel, vba, copy, filtering

I am working on a project where I filter column CI for "No" and "N/A", and if there are any results I want to copy the data in A:CD from the corresponding rows. How can I select the data in A:CD? I am working with 50,000+ rows of data so any offset loops would slow down the program too much. The last line of code before the End With is definitely incorrect.

```
Sub selectdata()

Sheets("Sheet_1").Select
Range("A1:CD1", Range("A1:CD1").End(xlDown)).Copy
Sheets("Sheet_2").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, 
_
             Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

Range("CE2:CP2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("CE2:CP" & Cells(Rows.Count, 
"D").End(xlUp).Row)

Range("CI1").Select
Selection.AutoFilter Field:=87, Criteria1:=Array( _
    "NO", "N/A"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
With ActiveSheet
If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Columns(1)) > 1 _
        Then .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Offset(1, -5).xlLeft.Copy

End With
End Sub
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To copy filtered data in A:CD

```
With ActiveSheet

    With Intersect(.Range("A:CD"), .UsedRange)
        .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
    End With

End With
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this... it copies without header to CE2.

You can alter your filter with this method by adjusting this line

```
 filterRange.AutoFilter Field:=87, Field:=87, Criteria1:="=N/A", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=NO"
```

**Code:**

```
Option Explicit

Sub selectdata()

    Dim sourceWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
    Dim targetSheet As Worksheet

    Set sourceWorkbook = ThisWorkbook
    Set sourceSheet = sourceWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set targetSheet = sourceWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

    With sourceSheet

        Dim lastRow As Long
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "CI").End(xlUp).Row

        Dim filterRange As Range

        Set filterRange = .Range("A1:CI" & lastRow)

        filterRange.AutoFilter

        filterRange.AutoFilter Field:=87, Field:=87, Criteria1:="=N/A", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=NO"

        With sourceSheet.AutoFilter.Range

            .Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 82).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy targetSheet.Range("CE2")

        End With

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Fantastic!! Much time saved by adding in the part to copy it to a new sheet. :)